# uninstall docker from windows - DockerToolbox

Tags: docker, docker-machine, boot2docker

unistall docker from windows

i'd like to uninstall completely  docker for windows (Dockertoolbox) to clean the system well and reinstall it again

so i've began to remove the default virtual machine like the documentation says:
https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/#how-to-uninstall-toolbox

so i did `docker-machine rm default`

```
C:\Users\a.pinato>docker-machine rm default
About to remove default
WARNING: This action will delete both local reference and remote instance.
Are you sure? (y/n): y
Error removing host "default": C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe unregistervm --delete default failed:
0%...10%...20%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage.exe: error: Machine delete failed
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not delete the medium storage unit 'C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.docker\machine\machines\default\disk.vmdk' (VERR_SHARING_VIOLATION)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleUnregisterVM(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 165 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
```

Comment: Are you running this action as a Admin?

Comment: ............yep

Answer (score 3):

from task manager i closed all instances of vboxheadless and i repeated `docker-machine rm default`

sucessfully removed